# "-(id) init" do not fire in ViewController when using storyboard

Tags: ios

I notice "-(id) init" in ViewController is not executed when using storyboard. is there any other method that could replace init, or is there is away to force firing init.

Comment: What are you trying to do? There are several other methods: `-initWithNibName:bundle:`, `-viewDidLoad`, `-viewDidAppear:`, etc. Depending on what you want to do, one of those may be a better choice.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

try to use

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) 
 {
        // Do something
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: I have the impression that the reason initWithNibName is not called is because you don't use a nib file with storyboards. Thank you @NeverBe, initWithCoder ran for me too.

Comment: +1 for @Ant - the code in the answer is the right solution, but missed the explanation - which was then cleared up.

Answer (score 3):

`- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundle` is called instead.

As the comment above indicates, you need to decide if there might be a more appropriate method to override. Keep in mind that the view has not yet been loaded in the initWithNibName method, so don't try to change anything there yet.