# How to initialise 2nd view controller form 1st view iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have found a project with expandable table view cells and it works great. The view controller is initialised in AppDelegate.m like this:

```
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    AccordionTableViewController *vc = [AccordionTableViewController new];
    self.window.rootViewController = vc;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

I have InboxTableViewController with some content and it has "Menu" button on it(push segue) which goes to the second ExpandableCellTableViewController. When I go to 2nd view, I only see empty cells. But when I use the code in AppDelagate - this view has all content that it supposed to, but in such case, this 2nd controller becomes initial and its the only accessible view.
So, my question is - why table view cells are empty, while it works when it is initialised in AppDelegate.m
I will add any other code that will be required as I am not sure what should I provide at this stage. Thank you.

EDIT: 
I have just found that arrays that hold data for tableview cells are empty when i NSLog them in `viewDidLoad` when the view initialised in my way (through button press). But works when initialised form AppDelegate.m.

I put NSLog into - (id)init but it seems like it is never called, and this is why data holding arrays are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I figured out that my data holding arrays are empty by logging them out in viewDidLoad. So I though, that they  don't get initialised. So I put NSLog in - (id) init and indeed,  init is never called. I searched for it and found this thread: [["-(id) init" do not fire in ViewController when using storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9216921/id-init-do-not-fire-in-viewcontroller-when-using-storyboard][1])

It suggested to use:

```
  - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder 
{
    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) 
 {
        // Do something
    }
    return self;
}
```

This worked for me.
Hope someone adds more details to this answer, explaining why it happens.

Answer (score 1):

What you will need to do is create another `UIViewController` whose `UIView` will contain nothing but a button. Now initialize that ViewController in your app delegate like you have dont in the code sample above.
Once that is done, add an action for the button in your `UIViewController` class and open up your new controller at this point.
Does this help ?

Comment: Hi, I have pretty much done the same as you stated above initially. I have InboxTableViewController with some content and it has "Menu" button on it(push segue) which goes to the second ExpandableCellTableViewController. When I go to 2nd view, I only see empty cells. But when I use the code in AppDelagate - this view has all content that it supposed to, but in such case, this 2nd controller becomes initial and its the only accessible view.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using the same AccordionTableViewController in your case above ? When you launch it from InboxTableViewController ?

Comment: That's right. It is exactly that controller with no changes. I have added some more details in the description. Thank you.

Comment: Can you check if the data source methods of the AccordionTableViewController are being hit ? Can you post the code for the AccordionTableViewController here ?

Comment: I have just browsed for "- (id) init is not called ios" and found thread where one suggests to use - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)aDecoder. And I have put arrays initialisation there and amazingly it worked. I do not know why though ) I really appreciate your effort. Thank you.